# How to call Update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As far as I understand, the `Update` method of a `MonoBehaviour` should be invoked in each frame, as long as the `MonoBehaviour` is linked (as a component) to an active [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html). This is also the way it is described e.g. [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/update-function-is-not-getting-called.330735/).

I am trying to develop a little application with Unity 2017.3. I have inserted a `GameObject` that is linked to a script:

[image: Unity UI showing the link between GameObject and script]

The script should output a debug message when `Update` is called:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        print("test b update");
    }
}
```

However, the console does not show any of my output after running the application:

[image: Unity console]

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Unity myself, but I use `Debug.Log()`. Is `print()` your method or a Unity thing?

Comment: @Crowcoder print just an alias to Debug.Log()

Comment: Where does those 'Build completed' logs coming from? Are you positive that you are pressing the play button on top?

Comment: You need to press "Play" not build the app if you want to see the long int the Console tab.

Comment: @Crowcoder: It's something built-in; I used it based upon the advice from [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/update-function-is-not-getting-called.330735/): "you are using Debug.Log(), don't use that, I didn't use C# outside of Unity engine, but I think this is console(cmd) output when you are making some native C# application. Use print() function instead."

Comment: @Thalthanas: "Are you positive that you are pressing the play button on top?" - indeed I was not. It wasn't clear to me what the media-player-like controls would do (or that I'd have to press "play" to execute my application). Coming from a general development background, "Build & Run" seemed like the intuitively straightforward thing to do for me. So, that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you console output I suppose that you're building your app and trying to launch it outside of Unity? If yes, keep in mind that `Debug.Log(), print()` print to console only when you're rinning your game in Unity editor. And when you build your app and then run it (on anything other than Unity's editor) this 2 functions will print to a logfile instead.
So to see the console output, you should run your app in Unity by pressing "play" button.

Comment: Coming from a general development background, "Build & Run" seemed like the straightforward thing to do for me; I didn't realize that the "Play" command would start an interactive version of the game. Thank you, this solves it.